# How to plot Comparative Boxplot with a PDF like KDnuggets Style

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot, probability-density

While going through the [Understanding Boxplots from the KDnuggets Article](https://www.kdnuggets.com/2019/11/understanding-boxplots.html). I found a detailed plot of Boxplot with a probability density function (pdf)

I'm trying to plot a comparative Boxplot and a probability density function (pdf)  as shown in the article as below fig

[image]

I know plotting a basic [box plot](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.boxplot.html) and [pdf](https://scipy-lectures.org/intro/scipy/auto_examples/plot_normal_distribution.html) individually. My knowledge of visualization was minimum.I'm not asking the exact replicate of the above Plot, a similar plot with detail would be highly appreciated.

**I'm open to new ideas and approaches and wanted to put some feelers out before diving into getting started**

**Can it be possible to plot the above plot with Python if YES, Which package would be used to plot the above plot? Can anybody shed some light on plotting the above plot with Python? I would be happy to receive any leads on it from you.**

Comment: You can refer to the Python [source code](https://github.com/mGalarnyk/Python_Tutorials/blob/master/Statistics/boxplot/box_plot.ipynb) here in 'jupyter notebook' format.

Comment: @r-beginners Thanks for the reference. It really helps a lot:).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is an attempt to recreate the graphical elements of the plot. Instead of a perfect normal distribution, some random data is used, so you can plug in your own data. (For a more perfect curve, generate a higher number of samples.)

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import seaborn as sns

x = np.random.normal(0, 1, 1000)
mean = x.mean()
std = x.std()
q1, median, q3 = np.percentile(x, [25, 50, 75])
iqr = q3 - q1

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(nrows=2, sharex=True)

medianprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=2, color='yellow')
sns.boxplot(x=x, color='lightcoral', saturation=1, medianprops=medianprops,
            flierprops={'markerfacecolor': 'mediumseagreen'}, whis=1.5, ax=ax1)

ticks = [mean + std * i for i in range(-4, 5)]
ticklabels = [f'${i}\\sigma$' for i in range(-4, 5)]
ax1.set_xticks(ticks)
ax1.set_xticklabels(ticklabels)
ax1.set_yticks([])
ax1.tick_params(labelbottom=True)
ax1.set_ylim(-1, 1.5)
ax1.errorbar([q1, q3], [1, 1], yerr=[-0.2, 0.2], color='black', lw=1)
ax1.text(q1, 0.6, 'Q1', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
ax1.text(q3, 0.6, 'Q3', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
ax1.text(median, -0.6, 'median', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
ax1.text(median, 1.2, 'IQR', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
ax1.text(q1 - 1.5*iqr, 0.4, 'Q1 - 1.5*IQR', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
ax1.text(q3 + 1.5*iqr, 0.4, 'Q3 + 1.5*IQR', ha='center', va='center', color='black')
# ax1.vlines([q1 - 1.5*iqr, q1, q3, q3 + 1.5*iqr], 0, -2, color='darkgrey', ls=':', clip_on=False, zorder=0)

sns.kdeplot(x, ax=ax2)
kdeline = ax2.lines[0]
xs = kdeline.get_xdata()
ys = kdeline.get_ydata()

ylims = ax2.get_ylim()
ax2.fill_between(xs, 0, ys, color='mediumseagreen')
ax2.fill_between(xs, 0, ys, where=(xs >= q1 - 1.5*iqr) & (xs <= q3 + 1.5*iqr), color='skyblue')
ax2.fill_between(xs, 0, ys, where=(xs >= q1) & (xs <= q3), color='lightcoral')
# ax2.vlines([q1 - 1.5*iqr, q1, q3, q3 + 1.5*iqr], 0, 100, color='darkgrey', ls=':', zorder=0)
ax2.set_ylim(0, ylims[1])
plt.show()
```

[image: example plot]

Some remarks:

- Often the median and the mean don't coincide, so the 0 sigma might be a bit off from the median line.
- Matplotlib draws the whiskers at the data point that is closest to the calculated `Q1 - 1.5 IQR` and `Q3 + 1.5 IQR`, so when there aren't a huge number of points, the position of the whisker might be off a bit.
- For real data, the distribution seldom looks like a perfect bell curve.

Here is an example for 1 million samples:

[image: plot for 1 million samples]

Comment: Nice answer Johan +1 and bookmark, even though it says to avoid these types of comments.

Comment: @johanC This is excellent. Thank you for your answer.  Adding text annotations (as KDnuggets) dynamically to the plot seems to be a bit difficult right??

Comment: @JohanC  I tried doing that(A function which takes any form of distribution), the plots are coming good, but I could not be able to generalize the positions of the text :)

Comment: I added texts for the boxplot. I left out the vertical lines, because the exact position depends on the nearest datapoints for the boxplot and the x-positions of the curve for the kdeplot.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this code. If you are using a recent version of matplotlib, use yerr=0.2