# how to draw a boxplot with PDF beside in R/Python？

Tags: matplotlib, ggplot2

an exampl is as follows:
[image]
the example is from origin software. It's easy to draw these two types separately, but is there some pakcgaes can combine them as the pic shows?

Comment: Please choose either one or the other. Don't post questions refering to both platforms. Please add some reproducible test data and your best-effort code.  Did you consider seaborn's `sns.violinplot(...)`?

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63351594/how-to-plot-comparative-boxplot-with-a-pdf-like-kdnuggets-style/63354295#63354295

Comment: this might help: [VISUALIZING DISTRIBUTIONS WITH RAINCLOUD PLOTS (AND HOW TO CREATE THEM WITH GGPLOT2)](https://www.cedricscherer.com/2021/06/06/visualizing-distributions-with-raincloud-plots-and-how-to-create-them-with-ggplot2/)